# Browser automatically scrolls to top when set overflow=hidden to html tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've faced with problem:
When I set overflow:hidden style to html tag, my page scrolls to top on my laptop(windows 8.1, chrome 42.0.2311.135m - last), but in IE and all browsers on my mac - everything is ok.
Here an example:https://jsfiddle.net/thrr35ee/1/;

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        var b = $(document).scrollTop();
        if(b > 400){
            $('html').css('overflow','hidden');
        }
    });
});
```

Why it happens? 
How to fix it? I tried to save position before setting overflow and after it scroll to position, but it works only if I do it after 1 second.

UPD:
It happens when I scroll the page while holding the mouse on the scrollbar, if I scroll by keys(up and down) - everything is ok.

Comment: tried adding height: 100% to html in css?

Comment: @Olli1511, yes i've tried

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Feels like there's a better way to do this.

Comment: @mattytommo, page should be non-scrolled when scroll position = target div offset, and should be scrolled when scroll position > target div offset + height of div, but this div should be visible, when page non-scrolled